# сертификат сервера не прошёл проверку подлинности

Tags: kubuntu

При запуске обновления программ вылезло окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У домена [opendesktop.org](http://opendesktop.org) закончился срок действия сертификата, о чём вас и информирует Muon. Если вы не параноик, то можете смело жать "Продолжить" и добавлять этот домен в список доверенных. В противном случае - ждите, пока opendesktop.org получит новый сертификат. Помните, что `apt-get` таких предупреждений не выдаёт, поэтому, если вы параноик, временно уберите opendesktop.org из списка источников обновлений (`/etc/apt/sources.list`).